# Cosmos Design Questions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have the following top level simplified design for my Cosmos project. Some introduction and then followed up by some questions. Thank you in advance for reading this.

I have 3 collections: `Memberships`, `Discounts` and `Vouchers`:

[image]

Each collection stores different entities. The entities in each collection are not the same but belong to the same partition and have inherited properties:

- `id` - unique id (a Cosmos requirement...I tink)
- `upsertDate` - updated at the time of upsert so i can order documents (see below)

Each collection entity has:

- `code` - the partition key
- `type` - a discriminator for the diffrent entities in the collection.

There are thousdans of memberships, vouchers and discounts. When the system receives a membership code, for example, it can quickly look up the document as it is the partition key.

If one does this, it returns all the entity documents that belong to the same `code`:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.code = 'YTR3IO'
```

If one does this, it returns all the entity documents that belong to the same `code` and `type`:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.code = 'YTR3IO' and c.type = 10
```

`type` is usually an enumeration for the different entities that can be stored in a specific collection. For example, in the case of memberships, type can be `notication`, `comment`, `request`, `transaction`, etc

The reason I have the `upsertDate` in every document so I can do things like this:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.code = 'YTR3IO' AND c.type = 10 ORDER BY c.upsertDate DESC
```

For the indexing policy, I have overridden the policy to what I think is best:

```
DocumentCollection collectionDefinition = new DocumentCollection();
collectionDefinition.Id = _docDbMembershipsCollectionName;
collectionDefinition.PartitionKey.Paths.Add("/code");
collectionDefinition.DefaultTimeToLive = -1;

// If queries are known upfront, index just the properties we need
collectionDefinition.IndexingPolicy.Automatic = true;
collectionDefinition.IndexingPolicy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.Consistent;
collectionDefinition.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Clear();

IncludedPath path = new IncludedPath();
path.Path = "/code/?";
path.Indexes.Add(new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 });
collectionDefinition.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(path);

path = new IncludedPath();
path.Path = "/upsertDate/?";
path.Indexes.Add(new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 });
collectionDefinition.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(path);

path = new IncludedPath();
path.Path = "/type/?";
path.Indexes.Add(new RangeIndex(DataType.Number) { Precision = -1 });
collectionDefinition.IndexingPolicy.IncludedPaths.Add(path);

collectionDefinition.IndexingPolicy.ExcludedPaths.Clear();
collectionDefinition.IndexingPolicy.ExcludedPaths.Add(new ExcludedPath { Path = "/*" });

DocumentCollection ttlEnabledCollection = await 
_docDbClient.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(
UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri(_docDbDatabaseName), collectionDefinition, new RequestOptions { OfferThroughput = 1000 });
```

QUESTIONS:

QUESTION 1: If I have a query that has oredering by the `upsertDate`, the cost shoots up the roof:

```
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 100, PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey(code.ToUpper()) };

var query =  this._docDbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<MembershipDeviceRegistrationItem>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_docDbDatabaseName, _docDbMembershipsCollectionName), queryOptions)
                .Where(e => e.CollectionType == MembershipCollectionTypes.DeviceRegistrationItem && e.Code.ToUpper() == code.ToUpper())
                .OrderByDescending(e => e.UpsertDate)
                .AsDocumentQuery();

List<MembershipDeviceRegistrationItem> allDocuments = new List<MembershipDeviceRegistrationItem>();
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    var queryResult = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<MembershipDeviceRegistrationItem>();
    cost += queryResult.RequestCharge;
    allDocuments.AddRange(queryResult.ToList());
}

return allDocuments.ToList();
```

How can I make use of the `upsertDate` to order my documents and select top most recent ones for example?

QUESTION 2: How do I calculate the cost of a query that has an aggregate?

```
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1, PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey(code.ToUpper()) };

return _docDbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<int>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_docDbDatabaseName, _docDbMembershipsCollectionName),
            new SqlQuerySpec()
            {
                QueryText = $"SELECT value count(m.id) FROM {_docDbMembershipsCollectionName} m WHERE m.code = @code AND m.collectionType = @type",
                Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
                {
                    new SqlParameter("@code", code.ToUpper()),
                    new SqlParameter("@type", MembershipCollectionTypes.DeviceRegistrationItem)
                }
            }, queryOptions).AsEnumerable().First();
```

QUESTION 3: I have a need to produce an Omni document that contains everything about a specific membership and return to some client so they can show its different parts. So I created something like this (simplified):

```
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey(code.ToUpper()) };
var query = _docDbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<dynamic>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_docDbDatabaseName, _docDbMembershipsCollectionName),
            new SqlQuerySpec()
            {
                QueryText = $"SELECT * FROM {_docDbMembershipsCollectionName} m WHERE m.code = @code",
                Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
                {
                    new SqlParameter("@code", code.ToUpper())
                }
            }, queryOptions).AsDocumentQuery();

List<dynamic> items = new List<dynamic>();
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    var queryResult = await query.ExecuteNextAsync();
    cost += queryResult.RequestCharge;
    items.AddRange(queryResult.ToList());
}

var omni = new DigitalMembershipOmni();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var collectionType = (MembershipCollectionTypes)item.collectionType;
    if (collectionType == MembershipCollectionTypes.Membership)
    {
        omni.Clone((DigitalMembership)item);
    }
    else if (collectionType == MembershipCollectionTypes.RefreshItem)
    {
        omni.RefreshItems.Add((DigitalMembershipRefreshItem)item);
    }
    else if (collectionType == MembershipCollectionTypes.OfferItem)
    {
        omni.OfferItems.Add((DigitalMembershipOfferItem)item);
    }
    else if (collectionType == MembershipCollectionTypes.TrackingTransactionItem)
    {
        omni.TrackingTransactionItems.Add((DigitalMembershipTrackingTransactionItem)item);
    }
    else if (collectionType == MembershipCollectionTypes.BookingTransactionItem)
    {
        omni.BookingTransactionItems.Add((DigitalMembershipBookingTransactionItem)item);
    }
    else if (collectionType == MembershipCollectionTypes.MembershipTransactionItem)
    {
        omni.MembershipTransactionItems.Add((DigitalMembershipTransactionItem)item);
    }
    else if (collectionType == DigitalMembershipCollectionTypes.NotificationItem)
    {
        omni.NotificationItems.Add((DigitalMembershipNotificationItem)item);
    }
    else if (collectionType == DigitalMembershipCollectionTypes.CommentItem)
    {
        omni.CommentItems.Add((DigitalMembershipCommentItem)item);
    }
    else if (collectionType == DigitalMembershipCollectionTypes.ContactUsItem)
    {
        omni.ContactUsItems.Add((DigitalMembershipContactUsItem)item);
    }
    else if (collectionType == DigitalMembershipCollectionTypes.ReferralItem)
    {
        omni.ReferralItems.Add((DigitalMembershipReferralItem)item);
    }
    else if (collectionType == DigitalMembershipCollectionTypes.EcertPinItem)
    {
        omni.EcertPinItems.Add((DigitalMembershipEcertPinItem)item);
    }
    else if (collectionType == DigitalMembershipCollectionTypes.ProfileUpdateItem)
    {
        omni.ProfileUpdateItems.Add((DigitalMembershipProfileUpdateItem)item);
    }
}

return omni;
```

The above works....but it is costly....and...it does not scale well....so if the a membership accumulates more data, the cost will go up signifcantly. I tried to do a query for each type specifying the top items to produce such as top 100 notifications...but the order by `upsertDate` (as noted above) makes the queries very expensive....so the total cost is even worst. How would one accomplish something like this with a reasonable cost and performance.

QUESTION 4: I have a `membershipCode` property in the `vouchers` and the `discounts` collections, how can I do a JOIN query that picks up the vouchers that belong to a specific membership without exhausting my RUs and killing my performance? I think JOIN queries will end up scanning the entire `vouchers` collection with different partitions and might have a significant cost and throughput issues. The only way I was able to get it to work reasonably well is to use Table DB to link `vouchers` to `memberships`. The Table DB queries are fast...but this added a significant complication to my little project.

I appreciate any pointer.

Regards

Comment: You do not wanna do count they way you do it right now. Use the CountAsync method of the SDK which makes the count retrieval significantly cheaper

Comment: You can also remove the `ToList()` from `allDocuments.AddRange(queryResult.ToList());`. queryResult has an enumarator so it will be added without it.

Comment: Ah...ok...thanks. But how would I calculate the `CountAsync` cost though?

Comment: You cannot directly but if you check the RUs on Azure portal you will see the difference.

Comment: I see...thanks for your clarification. So I cannot do it programatically. A little unfortunate because I keep track of cost and duration for each query and send to a log so i can analyze the results...this is why it is important to me.

Comment: Well you can choose between accurate high cost or inaccurate low cost on that one.